# Passing app configuration during the deployment (e.g. CF PUSH)

Tags: cloud-foundry

When deploying an application to Cloud Foundry (e.g. cf push), is there a way to attach application-specific configuration for this deployment?

I have an application artifact and I want to deploy it multiple times, each time with different app-specific configuration parameters.

I am aware that deployment manifest can define environment variables, but it is a fairly limited mechanism.

Is there a way to define/pass during the deployment process a rich configuration file or section, such as arbitrary YAML or JSON or XML or properties file, so a deployed application instance can read this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Investigate environment variables — you can pass them in via the app manifest [1] or via `cf set-env`

If you need to create a config file for you app, continue as above with env vars and create the config file dynamically via a .profile file in your repo (see example at [2])

[1] https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#env-block

[2] https://github.com/starkandwayne/ghost-for-cloudfoundry/blob/production/.profile

Comment: I would throw in a mention for using user-provided services. They are a little bit of additional structure on top of env variables. You can create a user provided service which is an arbitrary set of key/value data. That can then be bound to one or more service instances. The app can read this information like any other bound service, via the VCAP_SERVICES env variable. VCAP_SERVICES is a JSON blob, so it does have some structure. Beyond that, you're probably talking about a config service like Spring Cloud Config or Vault.